# C warnings, lcrypto lib. makes pointer from integer without a cast and others

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I have done my search and saw a lot of problems solved about warnings with pointers without cast, but after that I couldn't solve my problem and I still can't understand my warning.

So here it is a part of my code:

```
    RSA *rsa_private;
          .
        more code
          .
   rsa_private = PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(bio_private, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Here I have the following warning:

```
warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

Then I tried to solve my problem like this:

```
rsa_private = (RSA*) PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(bio_private, NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

(tried to solve the problem like this because te function looks like:`RSA *PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey` and as it returns a `RSA *` I tried to do a cast of it )

and then my warning began to be:`cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]`

Ok my point is, why I am getting the first warning? `rsa_private` is a `RSA *` and the function returns a `RSA *`, isn't it the same type?
Then when I put that cast why I get the that warning as well? (never saw it before)

And how should I correct my warning?

Comment: Have you included the correct header to get `PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey` Looks like your compiler doesn't know about it and so it thinks it is returning an `int`

Comment: Adding a cast is *not* the right solution; it just masks the warning, like putting tape over the "check engine" light on your car's dashboard. If you haven't `#include`d the header that declares `PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey`, then your compiler *should* have warned you about calling an undeclared function. Find out how to enable that warning. And then make sure you've `#include`d the correct header(s).

Comment: I see it makes sense, I will check my headers and do some tests, I will feedback asap!

Comment: Well it is correct thnx! the #include <openssl/pem.h>, was missing in my header, no more warnings thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we can read from the comments adding a cast is not the right solution for a warning.

And my compiler thinks that the `PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey` is returning an int (as correctly said in the comments), so the error is that my program is missing the `#include <openssl/pem.h>`, now compiler know that the function returns a  `RSA *` as `rsa_private` is also a `RSA *` no more warnings are showing up.